# Align input into list element

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

I would like to align my list as follow

[image]

The problem is the `input` box is stuck in "high" position.

Here is my code.

```css
#menu {
 float: right;
 width: 700px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}

#menu ul {
 float: right;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
 list-style: none;
 line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
 float: left;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#menu a {
 display: block;
 margin-right: 1px;
 padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #585858;
 border: none;
}

#menu .current_page_item a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu .current_page_item a {
 background: #2AA8D2;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="menu">
   <ul  style = "display:block">
    <li><input type="text" placeholder = "Search"/>&nbsp&nbsp<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Language</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle` in `li`

```css
#menu {
  float: right;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px red solid
}
#menu ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
  display:block
}
#menu li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu a {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #585858;
  border: none;
}
#menu .current_page_item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu .current_page_item a {
  background: #2AA8D2;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />&nbsp&nbsp<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portals</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Language</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Log In</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```